# Watch for component data changes not working as expected

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, watch

I'm making some experiments on front end with Vue.js and I defined a component like this:

```
<template id="order-item">
    <select v-model="item.product">
        ...
    </select>

    <input type="number" v-model="item.quantity">

    <textarea v-model="item.variants"></textarea>
</template>

<script>
    Vue.component('order-item', {
        props: ['idx', 'product', 'qty', 'variants'],
        template: '#order-item',
        data: function () {
            return {
                item: {
                    product: this.product,
                    quantity: this.qty,
                    variants: this.variants
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            item: function () {
                console.log("change")
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Every time a field of `item` changes I need to... do something (in the exemple I'm logging `"change"`). But the watcher doesn't work as expected.

To make it work I need to define a whatcher function for every `item`'s field, ie `item.quantity`, `item.variants`.

Is there a way to bind the watch to the whole `item` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VueJS doesn't watch the nested properties because of performance issues. But, yes it does provide us with a way to deep watch the objects and array.

Try replacing your watch object with:

```
watch: {
   item: {
       deep: true,
       handler() {
           console.log("change") 
       }
   }
}
```

You can learn more about watch properties [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).